# Maven not recognizing parameters when running custom mojo from CLI

Tags: java, maven

I am attempting to run a custom mojo through the command line (without a pom file)

```
mvn com.example.org:ei-mojos:1.0.073:apply-freemarker-template -DsrcDir=target -Dtemplate=createConfig.ftl -DoutputFile=config.json
```

But I am getting an error back from Maven

```
 Failed to execute goal com.example.org:ei-mojos:1.0.175:apply-freemarker-template (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'outputFile', 'templateName', 'srcDir' for goal com.example.org:ei-mojos:1.0.175:apply-freemarker-template are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

Here is a snippet of the mojo

```java
@Mojo(name = "apply-freemarker-template", requiresProject = false)
public class FreeMarkerMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * The source directory containing the input files.
     */
    @Parameter(required = true, readonly = true)
    private File srcDir;

    /**
     * The template file to be processed.
     */
    @Parameter(alias = "template", required = true, readonly = true)
    private String templateName;

    /**
     * The location of the output file.
     */
    @Parameter(required = true, readonly = true)
    private File outputFile;

    /**
     * Data models to be used during template processing.
     */
    @Parameter(required = false, readonly = true)
    private HashMap<String, String> dataModels;
```

Is it possible to invoke this plugin from the command line? Also, how would I go about specify the dataModels parameter? It looks like this in pom.xml

```xml
<configuration>
   <template>createconfig.ftl</template>
   <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/config.json</outputFile>
   <dataModels>
      <abc>abc.json</abc>
      <def>def.json</def>
      <xxx>xxx.json</xxx>
   </dataModels>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration parameters and Maven properties are not the same thing. You need to do something like

```java
@Mojo(name = "apply-freemarker-template", requiresProject = false)
public class FreeMarkerMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * The source directory containing the input files.
     */
    @Parameter(required = true, readonly = true)
    private File srcDir;

    /**
     * The template file to be processed.
     */
    @Parameter(property="template", alias = "template", required = true, readonly = true)
    private String templateName;

    /**
     * The location of the output file.
     */
    @Parameter(property="outputFile", required = true, readonly = true)
    private File outputFile;

    /**
     * Data models to be used during template processing.
     */
    @Parameter(property="dataModels", required = false, readonly = true)
    private HashMap<String, String> dataModels;
```